# Conversion from double to integer

Tags: c++, integer, decimal, pow

I am stuck in problem where the double number is not getting properly converted to integer.

**In this case->**

```
int x=1000;

double cuberoot=pow(x,(1/(double)3));

int a=cuberoot;

cout<<"cuberoot="<<cuberoot<<endl;

cout<<"a="<<a<<endl;
```

Output:

```
cuberoot=10
a=9
```

Why here a=9 and not 10?

Any solution to this problem??

**Also I don't want to round the value..if a=3.67 then it should be converted to 3 only
 and not 4.**

Comment: You can add a small positive to number and then calculate the root. Like `x=1000+0.05`. This would give `a=10`.

Comment: It is not the `cube` - That would be x^3

Answer (score 1):

Because the `cuberoot` is very close to 10 but not quite 10. `std::cout` truncates and rounds the number to 10, but a double to integer conversion will strip the decimal which is why `a = 9`. To solve this problem, you can use `std::round()`:

```
int a=round(cuberoot);
```

Comment: So any solution to this so that a=10 here?

Comment: use a round() function.

Comment: Actually problem is I don't want to round exactly.

Comment: I want that if a=3.99 then it should be converted to 3 only....any solution to this?

Comment: Right now `cube = 9.99...` and it is converting that to `a=9`

Comment: In above case where cuberoot=10 and when converted to int is 9 which i don't want...it should remain 10 as it is!

Comment: `cuberoot != 10`, it is equal to `9.9999999999999982...`. `cout` rounds when displaying the number

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see why!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int x = 1000;
    double cube = pow(x, 1.0/3.0);
    int a = cube;
    cout<<"cube="<< fixed << setprecision(16) << cube<<endl;
    cout<<"a="<<a<<endl;
}
```